`pathdef` not working when starting MATLAB from command line with `-sd` option
I'm starting MATLAB from the command line in Linux. I open it from a different directory using the -sd option (i.e. matlab -desktop -sd my/path/mydir) and MATLAB is able to correctly open into this directory. However, this directory (mydir) has a pathdef.m file, and yet the folders listed are not added to the path at startup.
As far as I know, the presence of this file in the startup directory should be enough to trigger the addition to the path? Or am I missing something?

How did you create the pathdef.m file? Are you sure it is correct?

i earlier added some folders to my path and used savepath ./pathdef.m whilst in mydir
